# Is there a way to make a project directory for all the external files, including textures and render saves?

Tags: workflow, blend-files, scene

I have been using blender for several years but I have never figured out if blender has a way to pack all the files from a scene, including blend files, textures, and render save files, in one folder like in Maya and other software?

Comment: Manny, it would very very helpful here if you thoroughly describe how you do these things right now so people can identify what areas/tools/scripts might work to help you with this problem.  Without a detailed description it's impossible to know what you currently do or how you might change what you are doing.  As your question is now, people can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean and not quite. While Maya has these files on disk, blend files are like an archive and have an internal folder-like structure where it organizes scene data/resources etc. Blender has a feature to pack external resources into your file such as textures/images (useful for appending/linking things later and creating reusable libraries).

[image]

I would argue that this is superior to how Maya or Max does it as you can simply pack a blend file and it will locate all external resources and group them into a single file. At anytime, you can always unpack the files to the current directory (usually just creates a textures folder).

Anyway, to answer your question, no it's not possible out of the box to automatically generate folders and have resources or renders to these predefined locations, if you want to mimic such behaviour, you can always create the folders and ensure that your file paths are relative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. In your operating system outside of blender, create a folder with a name like "Blender Project" (or perhaps something just a tiny bit more descriptive) before you start the project, and move or save all files pertinent to a particular project in that file. You can do the same thing from the file browser of Blender. Additionally, you can [pack image](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Applying_Image) files into a blender file.

Comment: Once you have all your assets in a single folder you can use "relative paths" so that if you transport your project to a different machine (or OS) your blender project will reconnect seamlessly.

Comment: Worth mentioning here is that you'll reference things by means of using [Relative Paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/open_save.html#files-blend-relative-paths) (two slashes like so: `//`, which refers to the root folder of your current .blend file).